# Organic or Homemade equivalent White board Cleaning liquid & scrub?

Tags: diy, alternatives

We have some white boards where the ink has dried.

I am sure there are commercial cleaners out there, but I am looking to find something:

**Liquid:**

- Organic/ Edible - Maybe as natural as a fruit/ veg/ herb extract

AND/ OR

- Home made - Using simple items from the kitchen/ garage

**Scrub:**

What would be the best scrub that will work well with the above?

Thoughts?

Comment: If it is just some text left over on the board, trace it with a fresh white board marker, then wipe dry. This will even help when people accidentally used a permanent marker on your board.

Answer (score 3):

I use lab alcohol for the ones in work. You need a solvent to free up the inks. At home I'd use methylated spirits (alcohol stove fuel). Flambe alcohol might work. You could test some vodka but the water content might be too high and make it smear.

Brown paper works well, screwed up. If you end up with lots in packaging you can recycle it for this.